# Is it possible to change the Skype indicator icon?

Tags: indicator, skype

I've searched high and low on my system for the image that is displayed in the Skype indicator but is *nowhere* to be found, even the Skype deb file doesn't have anything like it and no other Icon set changes the image.

Is it possible to? *at all?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be hard-coded in the binary. As long as it is not an open source program, you are not allowed to change it. The discussion regarding this [topic](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=988151) dates back to 2008!

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. Too much hassle to change one icon, but Thanks.